Create Azure OpenAI Validation failed
My application to access the Azure OpenAI Service has been approved. I tried to create a new Azure OpenAI resource in my resource group but failed.
When I am creating an Azure Open AI resource, it is not deploying.


I want to create an Azure OpenAI that I can use to create models in Azure AI Studio.

Have you opted standard pricing tier for your resource?


ERROR DETAILS Insufficient quota. Cannot create/update/move resource 'mynewaiproject'. (Code: InsufficientQuota)

Here you need to raise for quota request. Go to the Azure AI Studio portal at https://studio.azure.ai/ and sign in with the Azure account credentials.

Once signed in, navigate to the quota management section. This is typically found in the settings or account management area of Azure AI Studio.


Look for the option to request a quota increase specifically for compute resources. This will be labeled as "Request Quota".

Fill out the quota increase request form with details such as the reason for the increase, the specific compute resources you need more quota for, and any other relevant information.


Here, I opted "DALL-E model" for my resource and filled all the details and submitted.

Once the resource created then you can be able to deploy the models by following below.

Reference:

InsufficientQuota error while creating new AI project in Azure AI Studio


Thanks for clarification this problem
